# jQuery _renderItem display list of items?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to display a list of items using jQuerys autocomplete feature. This is my code of the success function:

```
success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function(v,i){
            parsedObjects = data['region.regions'][0]['region'];

            var item = [];
            var len = parsedObjects.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var obj = { name: parsedObjects[i]['name'], value: parsedObjects[i]['geoCodeId'] };
                item.push(obj);
            }
            console.log(item);

            response(item);

        }));
    }
```

The item object has all the name / value pairs I need. Now, how do I display those in my autocomplete input?

My _renderItem looks like that:

```
function (ul, item) {
    return $( "<li>" )
        .attr( "data-value", item.value )
        .append( item.label )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Do I have to use a loop or something?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Any way your approach is not so good.

```
success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function(v,i){
            parsedObjects = data['region.regions'][0]['region'];

            var item = [];
            var len = parsedObjects.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < i.length; i++) {
                var obj = { name: parsedObjects[i]['name'], value: parsedObjects[i]['geoCodeId'] };
                $("#list_cont").append(getElement(obj));
                item.push(obj);
            }

            console.log(item);

            response(item);

        }));
    }


    function getElement(item) {
        return $( "<li>" )
            .attr( "data-value", item.value )
            .append( item.label );          
    };
```

Your html should have something like this

```
<ul id="list_cont" ></ul>
```

If you want to implement auto complete widget use jquery in build functionalities like below.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

for additional information Refer [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: I mean you may use in built jquery functionalities instead of doing much.

Comment: Yes, but I have to use data coming back from an Ajax call, not predefined data. I am getting `ReferenceError: getElement is not defined`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that example, too, but the format there is jsonp, mine is json so it did not work for me. Is there a way to convert to jsonp?

Comment: There is no different between jsonp and json if you are not dealing with cross domain. jsonp is used only for cross domain request.

Comment: I tried the example, but my list stays empty when I use jsonp. Changing that to json gives me an empty list :). I am close but still not there.